# What is a solid hemisphere formally called?

Tags: terminology, solid-geometry

Quick question - if the formal name for the solid counterpart of a sphere is a ball, and the formal name for a "half-sphere" is a hemisphere, what is the formal name for the solid counterpart of a hemisphere?

Half ball? Hemi-ball? Just "solid hemisphere"? Is there even an agreed-upon formal name for this solid?

Comment: ?? hemispheroid ??

Comment: I believe that "hemi-ball" is the best option proposed by the OP, since it describes exactly what it is.

Comment: Hemorrhoid.......

Comment: I believe "Michael" is the best suggestion here. I  myself will be calling it Michael from now on.

Comment: Somewhat related [Johnson solids](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Johnson_solids). My favourite of those: snub disphenoid.